# 'Backward in Time' xkcd

Tags: javascript, math, date

The popular comic xkcd posed this equation for converting time complete into a date:

[image: Backward in Time]

I've been trying to do the same in JavaScript, although I keep getting `-Infinity`. Here's the code:

```
var p = 5; // Percent Complete 
var today = new Date(); 
today = today.getTime(); 
var t;
t = (today) - (Math.pow(Math.E, (20.3444 * Math.pow(p,3))) -
Math.pow(Math.E,3));
document.write(t + " years");
```

Time will return a huge number (milliseconds), and I know that the equation isn't meant to deal with milliseconds - so how would one do an advanced date equation with JavaScript?

Comment: rescale milliseconds to a different time unit. like femtoseconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made 3 mistakes:

1. `p` should be a decimal between 0 and 1 to indicate the ratio of progress completed.
2. The result is:
   `T = (current date) - (a number in years)`
   **not**
   `T = (current date - a number) in years`
   You need to first calculate `(e^…-e^3)` and then subtract that many years from `t`
3. You've forgotten a `+3` which was in the original formula

**EDIT:**

Here's some [working code as a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PSTfD/), although Javascript runs out of dates at around 75% completed

Comment: Is there any way to continue to 100(or 99)?

Comment: Well, obviously `Date`s break down because there wasn't really the concept of "October" back in 105000 BC. So, you might decide that past a certain point all you want is to calculate a year - which you can do with the calculations you've got

Comment: I know it sounds like I'm some kind of groveling idiot who is just getting into JavaScript and asking all the wrong questions, but for some reason this problem just escaped me. Thank for the advice Gareth, I'll see what I can do with it all.

Answer (score 2):

The percentage

```
var p = 5; // Percent Complete
```

should actually be `fraction complete`, so it becomes `0.05` for 5%. Then when going towards completion, `p` approaches 1 and the time approaches a finite limit.

With `p = 5` for 5% complete, the subtracted time would approach (roughly)

```
exp(20.3444*10^6)
```

when completion nears, which **far** exceeds the range of `double`, already `exp(40)` is millions of times the age of the universe and `exp(1000)` exceeds `double` range.

Comment: This in itself isn't the whole problem